# CSRF on login page

Tags: csrf

I have a CSRF Token on the login page, which works as expected. So when user has the login page open for a long time (the token has expired in the background). When they enter their login credentials correctly, it tells them that the action is invalid because the token has expired and redirects them to login page again, where they can now successfully enter.

I think the behavior is as expected, because the CSRF token has become stale and an explicit action has fetched the correct token. The users hate it because they need to enter the login information twice.

ANy advice? This seems like a very common problem with CSRF on a login page that sits there for a long time..

Thanks and appreciate any help.

Comment: Increase the lifetime or fetch new ones via AJAX. I am not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: you could automatically refresh the login page once every x minutes using javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1) Make the login a two page operation. Username on first page, password on next. There's no need to have CSRF protection on the username page. Users will understand a timeout on the password page.

Option 2) Have some JavaScript that displays a countdown if the page is open too long. If the timeout occurs, disable the login form and put a notice telling the user to refresh before continuing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15350123/14731 for why you might need CSRF tokens on the login page.

Comment: @Gili exactly. That's why you must keep CSRF on the second login page that has the password. The actual login operation must be protected. It's just the username page that can skip the CSRF protection